# Ask Ubuntu vs Ubuntu Forum

Tags: discussion

Are they (Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Forum) both belongs to Ubuntu.org?
Any guideline to put what type of questions on AskUbuntu or on UbuntuForum?

Comment: Welcome FrankL to Askubuntu, i think this question should go in the meta.stackexchange.com, this forum is dedicated for questions Diretly related to ubuntu, not the forum itself, try to post this question there

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is part of Stack Exchange. Ubuntu Forums are part of Canonical.

Answer (score 5):

AU is for a question with a specific answer or a problem that can be decomposed in to a specific number of questions with specific answers.  UF is for a problem that requires discussion.

Comment: UF is also for general discussion, not specifically QA